# How to remove a file ending in a dot . from a Azure File Share?

Tags: azure, azure-file-share

We somehow managed to create a file in an Azure File Share whose name ends in a **.** (dot) (the file name ends in . not the share name :) ).
We now cannot retrieve, remove, edit that file. Whenever we try to perform any action we get:

Extension
Microsoft_Azure_FileStorage

Content
FilePropertiesBladev2

Error code
404

Is there anyway we can remove this file using Powershell, Azure CLI, etc.?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

> Status Code: 404 - error

The above error indicates mostly **`File share`** or file present in the file share not found in the file storage.

According to this [MS-DOCS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-windows-file-connection-problems?tabs=azure-portal#unable-to-modify-moverename-or-delete-a-file-or-directory) check whether the file is locked for editing by another user also check if the file is open in another program.

> Is there anyway we can remove this file using Powershell, Azure CLI, etc.?

I tried in powershell and removed the .files successfully.

Initially I have some files in fileshare.

**Portal:**
[image]

**Commands:**

```
$sharename = "fileshare1"
$foldername = "directory1"
$accountname = "storage326123"
$accountkey = "<storage account key>"
az storage file delete --account-name $accountname --account-key $accountkey --share-name $sharename --path directory1/1..json
```

**Response:**

[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you Venkatesan, for taking the time to answer in detail. However, your answer doesn't cover the scenario we are facing. The file name ends in **.** (dot) (no extension). In your example, instead of the file you delete to be called **1.json** try with just **1.**

Comment: I tried without extension it worked. I have added without extension like name IExtension it is deleted.